# Is drift velocity directly or inversely proportional to the length of the conductor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

One way that drift velocity can be represented is: $$v_d = \frac lt$$
$$\Rightarrow v_d \propto l$$

However, another way it can also be represented is:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
v_d &=& \frac {I}{neA}\\
&=& \frac {\frac VR}{neA}\because I = \frac VR\\
&=& \frac {V}{RneA}\\
&=& \frac {V}{\rho \frac la neA} \because R = \rho\frac la\\
v_d &=& \frac {V}{\rho lne}
\Rightarrow v_d \propto \frac 1l\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

So which is correct?
Is $$v_d  \propto l$$ or is $$v_d \propto \frac 1l$$

Comment: I have suggested edits to improve your MathJaX, using that many spaces makes the code nearly unreadable when one can simply use equation array to get automatic lined equations. Though I will say props to the dedication of lining them up manually. Hopefully I haven't inadvertently erased a term or variable

Comment: Thank you so much @Triatticus for correcting my MathJAX and for the compliement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One way that drift velocity can be represented is: $$v_d = \frac lt$$
> $$\Rightarrow v_d \propto l$$

This is not a useful representation. In this representation $t$ is proportional to $l$, so you don’t have a useful proportionality.

The other one is better, but it is important to know what you are keeping constant and what you are allowing to change. Here you are keeping the area, material, and voltage constant.